# Nginx try_files - log hit / miss

Tags: nginx

I have two mounts:

- /mnt/nfs - an NFS mount that contain *a lot* of files.
- /mnt/ssd - a local SSD disk that acts as cache for the above nfs mount.

In nginx I have configure a location like so:

```
location ~ /my_location/(.*) {
  alias /mnt/;
  try_files ssd/$1 nfs/$1 =404;
}
```

This itself works just fine.

I would like to log when the file was found from ssd and when it was required to fetch it from the nfs mount.

Finding the file from **ssd** would be logged as **HIT**.

Having to go to **nfs** would be logged as **MISS**.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286850/nginx-try-files-with-multiple-named-locations

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I just came up with, using an extra named location:

```
location /my_location/ {
    alias /mnt/ssd/;
    set $file_source ssd;
    try_files $uri @nfs;
}

location @nfs {
    alias /mnt/nfs/;
    set $file_source nfs;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Now you know what to do with that new variable.