# May I use two named locations within try_files nginx directive?

Tags: nginx, location

I want to use something like:

```
location @a1 {
    ...
}

location @a2 {
    ...
}

location /path {
    try_files @a1 $uri @a2
}
```

Does it possible and what should I do at @a1 location to continue tries with $uri / @a2?

If so, how nginx will process that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NGINX try\_files with multiple named locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286850/nginx-try-files-with-multiple-named-locations)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found [this solution](http://linuxplayer.org/2013/06/nginx-try-files-on-multiple-named-location-or-server):

```
location /static/ {
    try_files $uri @static_svr1;
}
location @static_svr1{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.11$uri;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 = @static_svr2;
}

location @static_svr2{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.12$uri;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 = @static_svr3;
}

location @static_svr3{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.13$uri;
}
```

This example works like:

```
try_files $uri @static_svr1 @static_svr2 @static_svr3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not, because try_files will only treat its *last* parameter as a named location — in your example, nginx will look for a file named `@a1` and ignore the `location @a1` block.

The [try_files docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) aren’t super explicit about this, only mentioning that “the last parameter can also point to a named location”.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286850/nginx-try-files-with-multiple-named-locations#21294752) shows a workaround that uses [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page), which might be a useful approach for you (depending on what you want to do by stepping into `@a1`).

[More on try_files here](https://serverfault.com/questions/329592/how-does-try-files-work).